# parse.com background job triggering timeouts with cloud code function

Tags: parse-platform

I have written a cloud code function called approveDish that works within the timeout limits set by Parse.com when I call the function directly once from a client button.

However, I need to migrate some old database records to this and am wondering why when I run the background job with larger than say 3 results returned in the query I get timeouts in that cloud code function. Shouldn't this in a background job not timeout ever as we're calling things seriously?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("migrateDishesToChains", function(request, status){

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var Dishes = Parse.Object.extend("Dishes");
var query = new Parse.Query(Dishes);
query.notEqualTo("approved", true);
//dishes.equalTo("user", "JQd58QhOCO");
query.limit(1);
query.find().then(function(results) {
// Create a trivial resolved promise as a base case.
                var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
                _.each(results, function(result) {
                     // For each item, extend the promise with a function to delete it.
                         promise = promise.then(function() {
                            // Return a promise that will be  resolved when the delete is finished.
                            return Parse.Cloud.run("approveDish",     {dishID: result.id});
                        });
                        });
                return promise;

}).then(function() {

            status.success();

});

});
```

Comment: The background jobs has a timeout of 15 minutes. Does your custom function "approveDish" return a promise?

Comment: Is `_.each` actually iterating over at most 1 result or am I missing something? If you could format-indent your code, it would be easier to read.

Comment: First of all, you could try to remove status.sucess() - this will terminate whole job once it's reached. Check if your other method approveDish does not do anything asynchronous, as it could return to this context instantly but won't have enough time to finish its job.